# Convert timestamp to readable date/time with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a field in an MySQL database named last_login which is stored as an int(10).  I would like to echo the last_login data as a readable date/time.  Here is the code I currently have:

```
$timestamp = 1291575177;
echo date("h:i:s",$timestamp);
```

What is the proper way to add the last_login data from the MySQL database into the above code where the 1291575177 is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d:H:i:s',1291575177);
```

The output of that would be `2010-12-05:18:52:57`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$connection = mysql_connect("...");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT timestamp FROM example_table LIMIT 1", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc();
echo(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', intval($row['timestamp']))); // assuming that row['timestamp'] is a valid unix timestamp

mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  It appears that no matter what data is in the last_login field on the database, the output is: 
1969-12-31 18:00:00.

Comment: Then it seems like the data in your database is invalid somehow. 1969-12-31 18:00:00 is close the start of unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00). So is your value close to 0? Or what exact value are you trying to put in?

Comment: The value in the DB is 1291584907.  Which converts to Sun, 05 Dec 2010 22:00:16 GMT.  Perhaps I have something wrong...

Comment: I have also updated my answer. So now it parses the value (see intval()) before passing it to the date-function. Try using my updated version instead and see if that helps.

Comment: Same thing.  Maybe I have something wrong.  I changed timestamp to last_login as that is the field in the db that I am accessing. $result = mysql_query("SELECT last_login FROM awl_users LIMIT 1", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc();
echo(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', intval($row['last_login'])));

Comment: If you do var_dump($row); after your query, what do you get?

Comment: Ok. So what value is NULL? If you do var_dump($row['last_login']) what does that give you.

Comment: Same thing.  I sure appreciate your help and patience.  I've scoured the internet trying to find a way to do what I want to do and have had no luck.

Comment: What is "same thing"? do you get NULL or do you get "1291575177"? If you run die(intval($row['last_login'])); does that give you 1291575177? Since 1291575177 is a valid unix timestamp, that should work..

Comment: Sorry, same as in NULL 1969-12-31 18:00:00.  When I have this I get no text displayed:  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc();
echo(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', die(intval($row['last_login']))));

Comment: No because you cant have ’die’ in there. That will end the request immediatly arter the function return. So it returns NULL? I would say that you should focus on getting the corrwct data out of your database. Once you do that, the method will work.