# print date from database

Tags: php, date

When I pull the date out of the db, it comes back like this:

```
1314718511 
1314212730
1314210433
1314210352
```

I want like this:-

```
08/31/11 14:43:29 IST
```

Comment: Looks like a Unix timestamp to me (seconds since jan 1 1970 00:00:00).  Does the field in the db by any chance have an integer datatype?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to readable date/time with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361287/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-with-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `date()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), or the `DateTime` class (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) when you want to do transformations (like time zones).

Answer (score 0):

If your database is MySQL also check out the [from_unixtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) 
and [unix_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) functions.  You'll see you can do this conversion either at SQL level or as Rijk pointed out, in PHP.